# Azure Powershell to stop VM's in a subscription

Tags: powershell, azure

I am new to Powershell, and to be specific entirely new to Azure Powershell. I need to create a powershell script to switch off all the VM's found on a subscription. I guess this needs to be done with the help of management certificate. But not sure where to start. I just done some simple lines of code to list all VM's as shown below:

```
Add-AzureAccount -Environment "AzureCloud"
$subscription = "my-sub-scri-ption"
Select-AzureSubscription -Current "SubName"
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "SubName" 
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "VM1"
```

The output recieved is "Get-AzureVM : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: subscriptionId".

Can someone please help me in this regard?

****EDIT:****

The powershell script which I am using is given below:

```
Add-AzureAccount -Environment "AzureCloud"
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "My Subs"
$serviceName = "Service01"
$vmName = "Service01"
Get-AzureVM | Stop-AzureVM -Force
```

Though while running it shows script execution is successful, I can see still that vm is powered on. Please note that the serviceName and vmName is same in my case. Anything wrong here in my code?

****Re-Edit****
Executed code:

```
Add-AzureAccount -Environment "AzureCloud"
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "My Subs"
$serviceName = "Service01"
$vmName = "Service01"
Get-AzureVM
```

Error for the above code:

```
Get-AzureVM : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: subscriptionId
At D:\TC_PS\Untitled1.ps1:5 char:1
+ Get-AzureVM
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureVM], ArgumentNullException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.GetAzureVMCommand
```

Comment: Could you please print the Get-AzureVM result, because the posted code seems to be well formed

Comment: @Michael: Please see re-edit!!

Comment: that error happens when the selected subscription is not valid. Now I would run `Get-AzureSubscription | Remove-AzureSubscription` this will delete all your subscriptions (I think you run Set-AzureSubscription before add the accout), then just run `Add-AzureAccount`, after you login check your subscriptions just running `Get-AzureSubscription` you don't need to run Set-AzureSubscription (that is used to change the subscription, for example to set the current storage name), after you check the correct SubscriptionName just run `Select-AzureSubscription "MySubscriptionName"` then `Get-AzureVM`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start from here: [Getting Started with Windows Azure PowerShell](http://dennymichael.net/2013/08/02/getting-started-with-windows-azure-powershell/)

Then you can simply run `Get-AzureVM` that will return all the virtual machines for every cloud service.

To stop a VM: `Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName xxx -Name vm-test-01`

To stop all the VMs in the subscription simply run: `Get-AzureVM | Stop-AzureVM -Force`

The `-Force` switch is necessary to stop the last virtual machine of the cloud service, otherwise the system would throw an error when trying to stop the last VM in the service, to avoid drop all the resources of your published app.

If you don't specify the `-StayProvisioned` switch, the virtual machine will be deallocated. This is the default behavior of `Stop-AzureVM`.

Comment: Thanks. I want to stop(stop-deallocated) all vm's of a specific subscription with a single command. This is because in future number of VM's may change. So, can't pass these names. Any possibility for this?

Comment: Yes sure is possible, simply launch `Get-AzureVM | Stop-AzureVM -Force` the force is necessary to stop the last virtual machine of the cloud service.

Comment: Ok Micheal.. That's clear and good. I would like to deallocate the VM (to minimise the cost) along with the shutdown of VM. How that can be achieved..?

Comment: `Stop-AzureVM` will deallocate the machine if you don't specify the switch `-StayProvisioned`, so by default the Stop-AzureVM command deallocate the virtual machine.

Comment: Hello Michael, I just tried as shown below.. Though the script executed successfully, I can see still the VM as online and running.. Can you please tell me where I am making mistake?

Add-AzureAccount -Environment "AzureCloud"
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "subscription1"
$serviceName = "vm1"
$vmName = "vm1"
Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -Name $vmName

Comment: You should also select the subscription if you have more than one subscriptions, the rest of the code seems to be ok! Try to add -Force, but actually should not matter so much, because if it is the last vm in the service, you should just see a confirmation popup that ask you if you really want to continue deallocating the last vm and so on loosing the deployment VIP, just give a try with the -force switch.